# How to make versioning on a framework

Tags: ios, ios-frameworks

I'm using [iOS-Universal-Framework](https://github.com/kstenerud/iOS-Universal-Framework) to build my API framework.

It works fine but I would like to know how to make versioning on a framework.

By example I would like to add traces with framework version indications..

It seems that the framework does not read the framework.plist file to read bundle version info...